# ( Server Error ) Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)

Tags: sanity, next.js13

*Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this? I've tried everything I could find and nothing worked...*

[left the code "About.tsx" and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyw9G.png)

[This is the "helper" I use to render the images coming from sanity's cms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmo4H.png)

I already tried ( && ) and it didn't work

Exemple:

```
src={urlFor(pageInfo.profImage && pageInfo.profImage).url()}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **DO NOT** attach images of code. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your code as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)